# How to use jquery .defer or .done when validating a form (with unobtrusive) prior to submitting it or preventing submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

From other examples I've tried using defer and promise (first time), but it's not working.

I am using unobtrusive validation on my form. There is a submit, then I trap that submit event where I get the error count. However there I need to have a means of waiting until the error count function has completed and from there either call a function to gather my data and POST it (using AJAX), or not.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.Save', function() {
  $("#personEditForm").submit();
});

$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // check for ModelState.Errors with unobtrusive validation
  var promise = ValidateEditForm();
  promise.done(function() {
    alert("promiseDone");
  });

  ValidateEditForm();
  return false;
});

function ValidateEditForm() {
  var $errors = $('#personEditForm').find(".field-validation-error span");
  var errorCnt = 0;

  $errors.each(function() {
    errorCnt++;
  });
  if (errorCnt <= 0) {
    PostToServer();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `defer` or `done` here as the `each` loop to get the count is not async. That being said, you don't need the loop at all: `var errorCnt = $('#personEditForm .field-validation-error span").length` will work

Comment: Also note that if the `.Save` element is a `type="submit"` button within your form (as it should be for HTML validation and accessibility reasons) then you don't need the first `click` handler at all.

Comment: The submit button is not of type submit as validation has to occur , then if valid, I create a whole bunch of stringified serialized objects to postback..  but it seems it is not hitting the $(document).on("submit, "form",... function. (I placed an alert in it to check)

Comment: `The submit button is not of type submit as validation has to occur` validation should be triggered by the submit event, so that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I use the   $("#personEditForm").submit(); .. so same thing I guess? or not? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that if the `.Save` element is a `type="submit"` button within your form (as it should be for HTML validation and accessibility reasons) then you don't need the first `click` handler at all.

With regard to the issue, you do not need to use `defer` or `done` here at all, as nothing about your logic is asynchronous. As such, this will work fine:

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var isValid = ValidateEditForm();
  if (isValid) {
    PostToServer();
  } else {
    console.log('Form was invalid. Tell user...');
  }
});

function ValidateEditForm() {
  var errorCnt = $('#personEditForm .field-validation-error span').length;
  return errorCnt = 0;
}
```

Note the use of a single jQuery object selecting all the error `span` elements and getting the `length` property to find the count. This replaces the need for the loop.

Comment: Point re submt button is good thx.
but either way trapping it as a button click or specifying it as type=submit, the  $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e){ alert("here"); } is not firing. need to find out why first. thx

Comment: If you add your HTML to the question I can help you with thsat

Comment: Thanks, but found my error and your solution works.